# Cannot deploy Azure Function: Error calling sync triggers

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have an app that I try to deploy to Azure Functions. I am trying to use  use <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> as a solution for problem "Could not load file or assembly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" in PropertyGroup. But when I add that there I cannot properly deploy my app to Azure.

```
   func azure functionapp publish <app-name>
```

And then, I get following error:

```
    Azure.Functions.Cli.Common.CliException: Error calling sync triggers (BadRequest). Request ID = '8352b514-e606-4316-b316-9ad47ad1e3b5'.
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Helpers.RetryHelper.Retry(Func`1 func, Int32 retryCount, TimeSpan retryDelay, Boolean displayError) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Helpers\RetryHelper.cs:line 27
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.SyncTriggers(Site functionApp) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 520
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.PublishFunctionApp(Site functionApp, GitIgnoreParser ignoreParser, IDictionary`2 additionalAppSettings) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 504
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Actions.AzureActions.PublishFunctionAppAction.RunAsync() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Actions\AzureActions\PublishFunctionAppAction.cs:line 191
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.ConsoleApp.RunAsync[T](String[] args, IContainer container) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\ConsoleApp.cs:line 64
```

Version in csproj file:

TargetFrameworknetcoreapp 3.1

AzureFunctionsVersion v3

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue:

1. As you didn't mention the version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package, many workarounds saying that there are issues in some versions. Please check by downgrading or upgrading that [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/).
2. Try using this package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/7.0.0-preview.4.22251.1) instead of the package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.